# How do i install beautify in brackets editor

Tags: adobe-brackets

I am trying to install beautify via the extension manager but I'm getting an error:

" installation failed, unknown internal error"

i can see clearly that brackets is connected to internet because when i try to search for beautify extension i see the results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a problems with the beautify extension but the brackets installation itself. In particular, the local nodejs installation. See https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/12538. This seems to be preventing ANY extension from being installed.

If you navigate to the brackets directory you should see the local brackets node installation. In the console here type `node -v`. This should give you the node version, but if it gives you an error message then the problem is with that installation of node.

Are you on windows? I solved this problem by copying from my own installation of node the node.exe from `C:\Program Files\nodejs` to `C:\Program Files\Brackets`. Of course, I don't know if this could have any unforeseen side effects - but it seems to work.